# ember "link-to" helper to support "anchor to jump to an element in the page"

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to pass queryparams and anchor element name in the link-to. like this

`localhost.domain.com?get=100&interviewId=11#4`

I used query params to construct get=100&interview=11 , something like this

> {{#link-to 'domain.url' (query-params get=100
>   interviewId=11)class="btn btn-info"}}
>
> Link
>
> {{/link-to}}

```
How to generate the link with anchor using ember link-to ?
```

Note: Need solution with link-to only, `<a href="">` is not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to) addon,

```
ember install ember-href-to
```

You can use href-to helper to generate URL by providing queryParams and routeName.

```
(concat (href-to 'domain.url' (query-params get=100 interviewId=4)) propName)
```

Comment: it depends upon another variable.

Comment: then you can use concat helper along with href-to