# Link-to element on page in Ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I'm essentially trying to accomplish the following in EmberJS's handlebars with a href to the ID of an element on another page that has a long list of content.

I see that I can access things such as edit etc with EmberJS link-to (link-to guides) but nothing on linking to a particular portion of the page.  The regular HTML version for clarification:

```
index.html>
<a href="info.html#custom-section-3">My Section 3</a>
/index.html>


info.html>
...
<div id="custom-section-3">...</div>
...
/info.htm>
```

If this is a repeat question please direct me to the original, I haven't been able to locate info on this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358067/ember-link-to-helper-to-support-anchor-to-jump-to-an-element-in-the-page?rq=1

Comment: Very much, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ember "link-to" helper to support "anchor to jump to an element in the page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358067/ember-link-to-helper-to-support-anchor-to-jump-to-an-element-in-the-page)